# TIme Program No Output

Tags: java

I can compile this on BlueJ and it says no syntax errors. But when I click the window to show my output it is not there. I can't see the window. Does anyone know what could be wrong with my code?

```
class Time {
    // declaring instance variables
int hour, minute;
double second;

public Time () {
    this.hour = 0;
    this.minute= 0;
    this.second = 0.0;
         } // end constructor
} // end class
```

Comment: can you explain what output is expected from class declaration code?

Comment: How you are running this code ?

Answer (score 1):

You need a main method, every java program starts running from the main method :-

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   // do what you want in here
   // System.out.println(VariableName);
}
```

also you have a constructor that sets the variables but you arent doing anything to it, all you are doing is declaring and setting its value, if you want to display it to a console use `System.out.println(Variable Name);` inside your main method

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about the main method haha. I will use your suggestion. Would the variable name be time?

Comment: @JaneDoe1000 no probs, no the variable name would be hour or minute or second if the class is time

Comment: oh okay so that makes sense :)